# Adverb of frequency and singular noun

Tags: grammatical-number

- I ate apple A for breakfast.
- I ate apple B for lunch.
- I ate apple C for dinner.

I heard that “I ate an apple three times” means “I ate the same apple three times.” Then should I say “I ate (three) apples three times”?

[And I would say yes, it can, but it needs the help of context to say it. "A person should drive a car three times in their life" —there's no assumption that it's the same car. But I added context. You can't just create extremely short, spare sentences and then insist that they can't possibly mean a certain thing. In both this question and the one on ELL, they mean next to nothing with no further context. –
Andy Bonner]

I can’t choose one because the answers are different.

Comment: "I ate an apple with every meal today." Context makes it clear that it wasn't the same apple.

Comment: "*An* apple" means one **nonspecific** apple, and you ate one apple three times.  If you said, "I ate three apples three times", that would mean that on three separate occasions, you ate three apples, like three apples on Monday, three apples on Tuesday, and three apples on Wednesday.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I want this answer. Why do people keep saying ‘I ate an apple three times’ means ‘I ate the same apple three times’?

Comment: @user284747 Who is saying "I ate an apple three times" means that you ate the same apple three times?  I think all of these things have to be interpreted using context: obviously you can't eat one apple three times, so it must be different apples.